# JPA Self join error

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I have an error with my entities, my tables are:

**LANGUAGE**

> codLanguage (Primary Key)
>  
>   nameLanguage

**Device**

> idDevice(Primary Key)
>  nameDevice

**PHRASE**

> idPhraseGroup(Primary Key)
>  codlanguage(Primary Key)
>  idDevice
>   (Primary Key)
>  tex

I have problem with my entity Phrase,it is :

```
public class Phrase implements Serializable { 

    @EmbeddedId 
    private PhraseKey idPhrase; 

    private String text;

   //etc 
  //here my problem (*)

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="idPhrase.idPhraseGroup",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)   
    @JoinColumn(name = "idPhrase.idPhraseGroup", updatable = false, insertable = false,  referencedColumnName = "idPhrase.idPhraseGroup") 
    private List<Phrase> groupListPhrase; 
}

@Embeddable
public class PhraseKey implements Serializable { 

private Integer idPhraseGroup;
private String codLanguage;
private String idDevice;
---getter e setter 


}
```

I would you like to get a list of phrases with the same idPhraseGroup
for example  in Phrase table :

> idPhraseGroup | codLang |idDevice  | text
>
> 1             | ES      | 1        | mesa
>
> 1             | EN      | 1        | table

..but i've got this error:

> Exception Description: An incompatible mapping has been encountered 
>   This usually occurs when the cardinality of a mapping does not
>   correspond with the cardinality of its backpointer

Thanxs

Comment: I tried this : MapsId("idPhraseGroup")@OneToMany     private List<Phrase> groupListPhrase; but it doesn't work, it creates select * FROM PHRASE_PHRASE

Comment: @MapsId("idPhraseGroup")  
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "PHRASE")
    private List<Phrase> groupListPhrase; but i've got only one phrase

Comment: I would you like to get :  SELECT *  FROM PHRASE t0, PHRASE t1 
 WHERE  (t0.idPhraseGroup = 1)  AND    t1.idPhraseGroup = t0.idPhraseGroup  AND  (t1.codLanguage = t0.codLanguage)  AND (t1.idDevice = t0.idDevice)

Answer (score 0):

I do not see why you need the mapping, or how it can work.     You cannot use the basic mapping "idPhrase.idPhraseGroup" field in the mappedBy on a oneToMany because it does not describe a relationship.  A oneToMany generally relies on the other side having a manyToOne back, but in this case you dont.

If all you want is a collection of Phrase entities with a particular idPhaseGroup, just query for it using:
em.createQuery("select p from Phase p where p.idPhrase.idPhraseGroup = :phaseGroup").setParameter("phaseGroup", phaseGroupId);

I would remove the mapping unless you really need it cached within the Phaze entity.  If you do, it would be better mapped like:
@OneToMany 
@JoinColumn(name="IDPHASEGROUP", referencedColumnName="IDPHASEGROUP", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private List groupListPhrase;